# Indexed family of sets, union and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each natural number n, let

$$A_n = \{-2n,0,2n\}$$

$$\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = 2\mathbb{Z}$$

because

$$A_1 = \{-2,0,2\}, A_2 = \{-4,0,4\}, A_3 = \{-6,0,6\},...$$.

And

$$\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = \{0\}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: If your definition of $\mathbb N$ contains zero then yes. The intersections changes if the naturals don't contain zero.

Comment: @JohnDouma It looks the same with or without zero to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Did you copy-paste $A_2$ to $A_3$ (which is obviously wrong)?

Comment: No, never mind. I was thinking that $2$ and $-2$ would be contained in each set but I didn't read the question closely enough. Your solution is correct.

Comment: Yes, those is correct. But are you expected to give the proofs or just the results?